# Не компилируется приложение с ошибкой Duplicate resources

Tags: android

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> [layout/main] C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\Colesa\app\src\main\res\layouts\activities\layout\main.xml [layout/main] C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\Colesa\app\src\main\res\layouts\layout\main.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[layout/authorization] C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\Colesa\app\src\main\res\layouts\activities\layout\authorization.xml [layout/authorization] C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\Colesa\app\src\main\res\layouts\layout\authorization.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

о чем говорит эта ошибка, я ее частенько вижу уже, особенно если проект из гитХаба скачиваю.

Comment: значит, что в обной из библиотек уже есть ресурс под названием `main.xml`

Comment: Ок понял, спс, переименовал и все пошло

Comment: @metalurgus, вот почему вы всё время в комменты , а не в ответ ответ пишите?..

Comment: @metalurgus, Ну дак ответ же вы дали,  вы и должны писать в ответе, а если правильно то я утвержу данный ответ, не буду же я сам на свой же вопрос отвечать, тогда легче удалить.

А так пригодиться авось кому, гугл сюда перекинет.

Comment: Ок, приму к сведению. Просто как-то не думал, что потянет на ответ, максимум на полезный комментарий

Comment: @metalurgus, А что не так то?), вы коммент полезный дали, я поставил +1 к вашему комменту. Тут просто нельзя вопросы без ответов оставлять, в дальнейшем создавать их не возможно будет, я это так понял когда прочитал справку об этом сайте. Потом `Юрий` дал аналогичный уже ответ, я и принял его, хотите можете вы ответ написать, я ваш засчитаю так как вы быстрее ответили, хотя и в комментах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно комменту @metalurgus:

Ошибка значит, что в обной из библиотек уже есть ресурс под названием main.xml

Следовательно надо переименовать ресурсы, вызывающие конфликты.